# Tricky normalize a specific column within a dataframe using a calculated field logic (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Take the delta between ['rounded_sum'] and ['rounded_sum_2']. Once found,  subtract or add this delta to the ['Q4 28'] column. Making sure the sum of columns [Q1 28 - Q4 28] is equivalent to the ['rounded_sum'] column.

**Data**

```
Location    range   type    Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   rounded_sum rounded_sum_2
NY          low_r   AA      2       0       0       0       2           2
NY          low_r   AA      2       2       2       6       8           12
NY          low_g   BB      0       0       0       0       0           0
NY          low_g   BB      0       0       2       4       4           6
CA          low_r   AA      0       2       4       4       6           10
CA          low_r   AA      2       2       4       8       12          16
CA          low_g   BB      0       0       0       0       0           0
CA          low_g   BB      0       0       0       2       2           2
```

**Desired**

```
 Location   range   type    Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   rounded_sum rounded_sum_2
    NY      low_r   AA      2       0       0       0       2           2
    NY      low_r   AA      2       2       2       2       8           12
    NY      low_g   BB      0       0       0       0       0           0
    NY      low_g   BB      0       0       2       2       4           6
    CA      low_r   AA      0       2       4       0       6           10
    CA      low_r   AA      2       2       4       4       12          16
    CA      low_g   BB      0       0       0       0       0           0
    CA      low_g   BB      0       0       0       2       2           2
```

**Doing**

```
delta = df['rounded_sum'].sub(df['rounded_sum_2'])
```

#add or subtract delta to [Q4 28']

```
df['Q4 28'] = df['Q4 28'].add(delta)
```

I believe I can use a calculated field, but still researching, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: your explain is not clear. needs additional clarification

Comment: ok I updated a bit - looking to find the delta between ['rounded_sum'] and ['rounded_sum_2']; once found I would like to subtract or add this delta to ['Q4 28'] column so that the sum of Q1 28 - Q4 28 remains the same as the rounded sum column @PandaKim

Comment: Seems your solution working like need, what is problem there?

Comment: Hi @jezrael no it is not quite working, as it is only adding the delta and not checking for the Q1-Q4 sum equivalent . I will keep researching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
df['Q4 28'] = df['rounded_sum'].sub(df.loc[:, 'Q1 28':'Q3 28'].sum(axis=1))
```

output:

```
 Location   range   type    Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   rounded_sum rounded_sum_2
    NY      low_r   AA      2       0       0       0       2           2
    NY      low_r   AA      2       2       2       2       8           12
    NY      low_g   BB      0       0       0       0       0           0
    NY      low_g   BB      0       0       2       2       4           6
    CA      low_r   AA      0       2       4       0       6           10
    CA      low_r   AA      2       2       4       4       12          16
    CA      low_g   BB      0       0       0       0       0           0
    CA      low_g   BB      0       0       0       2       2           2
```

**intermediate**

```
df.loc[:, 'Q1 28':'Q3 28'].sum(axis=1)
```

sum of Q1 ~ Q3

```
0    2
1    6
2    0
3    2
4    6
5    8
6    0
7    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

> so that the sum of Q1 28 - Q4 28 remains the same as the rounded sum column

You can check the sum:

```
df['Q4 28'] += df['rounded_sum'] - df['rounded_sum_2']
check = df.filter(like='28').sum(axis=1) == df['rounded_sum']
```

Output:

```
>>> check
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hi @corralien thank you - the values that are false has a delta that must be either added or subtracted from the Q4 28 column. The sum of Q1-Q4 must equal the [‘rounded_sum’] column

Comment: In fact if you add values the sum of Q1-4 are equal to rounded_sum. Do you have a case where it's not true?

Comment: Hi corralien - they are equal to rounded sum 2, but not equal to rounded sum..

Comment: In your sample, all are equal to rounded_sum. So I think I don't get it.

Comment: Yes In the desired output, the sum of q1-q4 equal [‘rounded_sum’] column because we either added or subtracted a value from Q4 28. In the original data, the sum of Q1-Q4 does not equal ‘rounded_sum’ column.